# Vue - loading div when data is re-rendered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, watch

I'm doing a list component with v-for and a function. Every time I change filters it re-renders the list. I did a div for loading message every time its changing, but I'm not sure exactly how to handle it.

This is an uncompleted code, but its easier to you read:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Filters 
        :country-selected="countrySelected" :countries="countries" 
        @updateCountry="countrySelected = $event"
        ></Filters>

        <section class="teams container-wrapper">
            <!-- Loading Placeholder -->
            <div class="loading-msg" :class="{'is-open': loading}">
                <p>Loading...</p>
            </div>
            <!-- List -->
            <div class="teams-list" :class="{'is-loading': loading}">
                <team-list class="teams"
                    v-for="(team, index) in loadingTeams()" :key="index"
                    :lorem=team.lorem
                ></team-list>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            teams: json.teams,
            countries: json.countries,
            countrySelected: "",

            teamList: undefined, //to watch
            loading: true //variable to toggle
        }
    },


    watch: {
        teamList: function() {
            this.loading = true // => THIS LINE EXECUTES AN INFINTE LOOP
            setTimeout(() => this.loading = false, 1000)
        }
    },

    methods: {
        teamFilters: function() {
            return this.teams.filter(
                team => team.country = this.countrySelected
            )
        },

        loadingTeams: function() {
            this.teamList = this.teamFilters()
            return this.teamFilters()
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
.is-open {
    opacity: 1;
}

.is-loading {
    opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

Probably there is an easy way to handle list update and toogle loading div (i would like to know your opinions), but I'm not understading why the function in watch 'teamList' is doing a infinite loop. It should work, right?

Comment: I don't see any watch function in your code.  Can you explain a little more the line of code that is causing the problem?

Comment: Edit: its watch property. Inside there is a function to execute every time teamList changes.

Comment: Basically, my team-list component is rendered by a function (with v-for) that is change with filters. So when filters are changed, new list is filtered and 'teamList' is a data property to detect changes and handle loading div.

Comment: So are you just asking how to display a "loading" div somewhere on the page?

Comment: Hmmm? Sorry if I'm confusing to explain, the question is how to show and hide when list is re-rendered (I need to fake it, so I'm using setTimeout). P.S.: Do you understand this Vue structure, right?

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you're asking.  I don't know of a way to do this.  Usually, "loading"/"waiting" divs are used on external calls (API) which can last a second or two.  Re-rendering a list in the browser usually happens very quickly thanks to Vue's virtual DOM.  Are you seeing a long delay in the `v-for` rendering?

Comment: No, but its a requirement to have a delay, even for UX requirements. (I'm thinking in alternatives, should be easy... but I want to understand I this is not working)